# Worldwide technology price comparison service?

Tags: shopping

As I find myself often in a different country (sorry, I like it and I seem unable to stop), and as I sometime happen to need some tech gadget I was starting to think to join both and somehow plan in advance the new purchases. Or maybe the place to go.

So, question is extremely simple (so to say):

**Is there some index we can use to measure prices for tech things across the world?**

A composite index or specific indexes would be both good, or even some kind of shopping search engine that is common across most nations on earth (and that can be used that way...if one exists but it check my IP and give me results only for my nation, that's not good)

---

Preamble before answers start repeating the same stuff again (questions like this have already been asked, but I didn't find a definitive answer)

- I am aware of import costs, limits, laws, and what else: they are out of the scope of this question.
- I am aware that traveling do not come for free: please do not answer with things like "even if it could be cheaper you will have to pay the flight ticket"

This question is not asking for advices or your opinions -*beware, those are even prohibited for site policies*-, just for simple facts. Thanks all!

Comment: Maybe someone can come up with a better title? I'd really appreciate that :-)

Comment: What a great question - weird anyone voted to close it.  moto, you know about the "McDonalds Index" published by *The Economist* right?  Perhaps they additionally throw in a "gadget index" - you should check?

Comment: (And just BTW, I have never found anywhere cheaper than HK - it's the solution!)

Comment: Hm, maybe we can narrow the scope to phones, laptops, and small gadgetry? Otherwise "technology" can encompass everything from washing machines to jet planes. And while I'm not sure why someone would be buying a fridge abroad while backpacking, I'm not going to judge.... ;-)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas no chance I can fit a fridge on my motorbike, yeah ;-D I did not specify a single type of gadget as I feel it would be just too personal and useless to other people (do you really all need a new lens for you Pentax? ;-D), so I decided to let answers focus on a global index, a specific one, or something entirely different (it's something I've seen happen on many other SE sites). But, as I'm not a native English speaker, I will not take offence if someone come out with the right words to narrow it to the  "class" of tech you are suggesting and edit the q. accordingly :-)

Comment: @JoeBlow: good idea, I'll check for it on The Economist. About HK...yeah, it's a bit outside my reach at the moment, but...never say never :-D

Comment: Check out the charts listing the iPhone price for each country. This should be a great way of approximating the cost of other electronics.

Comment: @JonathanReez iPhone is not an electronic product, just a status symbol, as such its price is not defined by the usual market prices but from the local culture. For example Italy has by far not the highest prices for tech in the world, yet it's the second country for the cost of an iPhone.

Comment: hey moto, the word for that they say is a "Velben" good: you're asserting an iPhone is a "Velben" good.  (I really don't know (or care) if that's true or not - I'm just saying it's a handy word for the concept you're expressing there.) You can google it up!

Comment: @motoDrizzt you can do the same with Samsung Galaxy phones

Comment: Cost-of-living index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost-of-living_index e.g. https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living